# Removing blank rows from Memmapped array

Tags: python, numpy

I have around 6000 json.gz files totalling 24GB which I need to do various calculations on. 
Because I have no clue about the number of lines I'm going to pick up from each JSON file, (since I would reject some lines with invalid data), I estimated a maximum of `2000` lines from each JSON.

I created a Memmapped Numpy with array shape `(6000*2000,10)` and parsed data from the `json.gz` into the Memmapped numpy [Total size=2.5GB]

In the end it turned out that because of the overestimation, the last 10-15% of the rows are all zeroes. Now because of the nature of my computation I need to remove these invalid rows from the Memmapped numpy. Priority is of course *time* and after that *memory*.

What could be the best method to do this? **I'm programatically aware of the exact indices of the rows to be removed**.

1. Create another Memmaped array with the correct shape and size, slice the original array into this.
2. Use the `delete()` function
3. Use Masking
4. Something else?

Comment: Could you load into a normal NumPy array the right length from the outset, using np.fromiter (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html)?

Answer (score 0):

[You can use `arr.base.resize`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20932361/190597) to truncate or enlarge the array, then `arr.flush()` to save the change to disk:

```
In [169]: N = 10**6

In [170]: filename = '/tmp/test.dat'

In [171]: arr = np.memmap(filename, mode='w+', shape=(N,))

In [172]: arr.base.resize(N//2)

In [173]: arr.flush()

In [174]: arr = np.memmap(filename, mode='r')

In [175]: arr.shape
Out[175]: (500000,)

In [176]: arr.size == N//2
Out[176]: True
```