# Pandas/Numpy and Larger than memory array of strings

Tags: python, numpy, memory, memory-mapped-files

I have a data set that's larger than memory and I need to process it.
I am not experienced in this subject thus any directions can help.

I mostly figured out how to load the raw data as chunks but I need to process it and save the results, which likely to also be larger than memory.
I have seen that pandas, numpy and python all support some form of `memmap` but I don't exactly understand how to go about and handle it.
I expected an abstraction to be able to use my disk as I use my ram and interface with the object saved on disk as normal python/numpy/etc object when using memmap... but that isn't working for me whatsoever

```py
# Create file to store the results in
x = np.require(np.lib.format.open_memmap('bla.npy',mode='w+'), requirements=['O'])
# Mutate it and hopefully these changes will be reflected in the file on disk?
x.resize(10,refcheck=False)
x
memmap([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
x.flush()
y = np.require(np.lib.format.open_memmap('bla.npy',mode='r+'), requirements=['O'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/RedditAnalysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 870, in open_memmap
    shape, fortran_order, dtype = _read_array_header(fp, version)
  File "/root/RedditAnalysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 614, in _read_array_header
    raise ValueError(msg.format(d['shape']))
ValueError: shape is not valid: None
x[:] = list(range(10))
x
memmap([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
x.flush()
y = np.require(np.lib.format.open_memmap('bla.npy',mode='r+'), requirements=['O'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/RedditAnalysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 870, in open_memmap
    shape, fortran_order, dtype = _read_array_header(fp, version)
  File "/root/RedditAnalysis/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 614, in _read_array_header
    raise ValueError(msg.format(d['shape']))
ValueError: shape is not valid: None
```

Which means the resize isn't being saved to disk

Any suggestion?

Comment: You might want to look into dask, which was designed for data that does not fit into memory. It has a pandas-like interface. https://dask.org/

Comment: Thanks @jakub! I looked at dask and implemented some solution! However I am struggling to use my compressed files and parallelize it. I considering migrating my entire dataset into a different format or maybe even a database as dask has been proving difficult in that area.

Answer (score 0):

`np.require()` makes a copy of the memmap array, since it doesn't "own" its data. According to the `open_memmap()` docs, you have to specify the shape when you open a file for writing. Otherwise, it writes "None" as the shape, which makes the `y` array `open_memmap()` call fail.

It looks like memmap arrays don't support resizing with `.resize()` (see [numpy issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4198)), but there's a workaround in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21110768) if you need that.

Comment: I need a solution without specifying the shape manually